# Find all files with the exact extension in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get all the files that end with ".asp" but I also get the files that ends in ".aspx" or ".asp..." when I do :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -Filter *.asp -Recurse | % {$_.FullName}
```

For the example, let's say I have a directory with test1.asp, test2.aspx and test3.asp, if I execute my script, the output will be:

```
C:\test\test1.asp
C:\test\test2.aspx
C:\test\test3.asp
```

but I only wanted it to get me "test1.asp and test3.asp".
For information, I use Powershell 2.1.

Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: If that's not a typo you should urgently update to a supported version of PowerShell. I tried in v5.1 and v7.1 and it's working there just as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot switch to another version, but thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a go with `Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -Match '\.asp$'} | % {$_.FullName}`. The -Filter appears to behave the same way as `ls *.asp` does, which is a bit lax.

Comment: @Olaf and I got different results for PS version 5.1, see my answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75351296/2883733).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check one more the last 3 symbols

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test' -Filter '*.asp' -Recurse |
Where {$_.Name.substring($_.Name.length -3, 3)  -Match 'asp'} | % {$_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** PowerShell behavior seems to have changed!

*Windows PowerShell 5.1.19041.2364:*

```
PS C:\Users\OA> Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\Test" -Filter "*.txt"

    Verzeichnis: C:\Test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        05.02.2023     09:59              0 TestFile.txt
-a----        05.02.2023     09:59              0 TestFile.txtLirumLarumLöffelstiel
```

*PowerShell Core 7.3.2:*

```
PS C:\Users\OA> Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\Test" -Filter "*.txt"

    Directory: C:\Test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          05.02.2023    09:59              0 TestFile.txt
```

Both commands were performed on Microsoft Windows Pro 10.0.19045.2546 (22H2).

Behavior on legacy operating systems: PS version 2.0 on Windows XP (using wildcard path instead of -File parameter) and PS version 5.14409.1018 on Windows 7: both have the former behavior.

**Edit:** For Windows 11, version 10.0.22621 (22H2) the behavior is the same as for Windows 10.

Comment: It seems like the behaviour does not only depend on the Windows and PowerShell version. I just updated my system to 22H2 and get still the same result. It just works as expected on my system.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf This is mysterious. Thanks a lot for your effort and checking!